# Java loop vertical

Tags: java, loops, integer, java.util.scanner, do-while

My code basically arranged the number into reverse order for example 415 the program will arrange it into 514 well my code is correct but I have a problem the output should be vertical.

> ```
> expected output
> 5
> 1
> 4
> ```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = in.nextInt();
    int rev=0;
    while( num != 0 )
      {
          rev = rev * 10;
          rev = rev + num%10;
          num = num/10;
      }
          System.out.println(rev);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to do it like this:

```
while( num != 0 )
{
    System.out.println(num % 10);
    num = num / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving this as an alternate method. By this you can take int which are are too big to fit in int datatype

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = in.nextLine();
for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
}
```